# How to avoid cutting off decimal places when using FORMAT( )

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have a number like 123456789.9876

I want to format it so that it displays as such 123,456,789.9876.

When I try `SELECT FORMAT(123456789.9876, 'N')`, I get the following result 123,456,789.99

Comment: maybe try using `'G'` in place of `'N'`.  The SQL Server FORMAT function does what it does, and the behavior we observe conforms pretty well to the provided specification:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-format-with-numeric-types

Comment: 'G' does not add the commas

Comment: format(123456789.9876,'#,##0.####')   for optional decimals , or for fixed  format(123456789.98  ,'#,##0.0000')

Comment: Honestly, just don't `FORMAT` your data in the SQL layer; this is something for the presentation layer.

Comment: echoing @JohnCappelletti, SQL Server `FORMAT` function will accept custom format string like `'#,##0.0000'` or `'#,##0.####'`  Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: After John Cappelletti pointed out in the comment.
you should use

```
SELECT FORMAT(123456789.9876, '#,##0.#####')
```

> I understand your pain. This is what I have done
>
> SELECT FORMAT(123456789.9876, '###,###,###,###.#####')
>
> [db fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a798128dd5257ed90a410342e95bf24b)

note that adding extra # do not pads with 0s.
So if you need to do (24 precision and 8 scale) do like
'#,###,###,###,###,###.########'

Comment: Millions and Billions not necessary.   Also just for fun try FORMAT(0,'#,###.#####') vs  FORMAT(0,'#,##0.#####')

Comment: @JohnCappelletti if you put the comment as answer let me know, I'll delete mine.